# Troubleshooting unwind segue Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift

I have been trying to add unwindSegues to a project and i'm having a problem making a connection from the button to the Exit. I have the line of code, below, in the destination file (the Start view), but for some reason, when I control-drag to the exit, it is not register as a connection point.

```
 @IBAction func unwindToStart(unwindSegue: UIStoryboardSegue) {   
 }
```

This problem only occurs occasionally, and not on every project. Any thoughts as to what I'm missing, or should investigate is appreciated.

Comment: It does sound like you are doing everything right. Unwind sequel are something I haven't don't too much. IIRC, a few things are absolutely required - IB, an embedded navigation controller (I think, could be wrong here) and a properly connected segue. All of which it seems like you have. So maybe it's *using* IB? The control-drag to this exit?

Comment: Sometimes you have to quit and restart Xcode, even cleaning out the derived data cache, to get it to work right. Or you might have that function in the wrong place, of course; it has to be a method of some view controller, but you have not proven to us that it is.